# Assigning icon to custom filetype on android

Tags: android

How do I do it so that when I open the file manager on android, the custom filetype will be shown with a personal icon

Answer (score 1):

That's not really possible, unless you are the one writing the file manager. There is no built-in "get an icon for a MIME type" system in Android, let alone a way for you to register a custom MIME type there.